# Silverlight 4 business application themes

Tags: silverlight, coding-style, silverlight-4.0, themes, business-application

We are starting a new SilverLight 4 Business Application project and are looking for theme. All we can find on the web are Navigation Application themes, which when applied to business application project, don't work. Most even have compilation errors.

Is there a place on the web to get theme specifically for that project or is there a way to translate navigation application theme into business application theme?

Thank you

Comment: Even I am very much interested in this. Have you found a way around this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got around finding some.

Here goes :

http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/site/search?f[0].Type=RootCategory&f[0].Value=themes&f[0].Text=Themes&f[1].Type=Tag&f[1].Value=RIAServices

Answer (score 1):

Repair RIA Service using below link that issue/error will be solved.
http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/1/241B26FF-EC1E-41FE-A782-E669C28A0A00/RiaServices.msi

Answer (score 0):

There are application themes for Silverlight 4 templates at [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e9da0eb8-f31b-4490-85b8-92c2f807df9e&displaylang=en).

Comment: Thos are not RIA service or business application template theme. I finally found some. look in my answer.